# Code not reaching SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a user control contined in `MyPage.aspx`. 
The user control contains few drop-down lists; each with `Autopostback = true` but when I run the code & change the drop-down item, other events gets fired but not `SelectedIndexChanged`.

```xml
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddPages1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true"
    onselectedindexchanged="ddPages1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind of ascx:

```
protected void ddPages1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

ascx also has `ReportViewer` & I'm populating number of pages in the report into drop-down list.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    TotalPages = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.GetTotalPages();
    txtPageCount1.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPages);
    if (TotalPages > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= TotalPages; i++)
        {
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
            listItem.Value = i.ToString();
            listItem.Text = i.ToString(); 
            ddPages1.Items.Add(listItem);
        }  
    }
    base.Render(writer);
 }
```

Comment: Is the SelectedIndexChanged listener contained in the user control's code behind? Also, are you databinding the lists?

Comment: Are you using data binding to populate the drop down list? If so, can we see the code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Where you have `ddPages1.Items.Add(listItem);`, replace it with

```
if(!this.IsPostBack)
{
    ddPages1.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```

The problem you could be having here is that by populating the list every time, you will be losing the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information? How do you bind to the SelectedIndexChanged event? Are you binding it programmatically? or using the declarative form?

Have you enabled ViewState?

Comment: Agreed, more info would help. Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Sorry for that. I've updated the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You have the set the `Autopostback = true` on your dropdownlist, but probably you dint put the `Autopostback = true` on your **usercontrol**

Comment: It would be better if you can explain how your are populating the data in the drop down list